# Reversing linked list using double pointers and recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, reverse, singly-linked-list

I know there are a lot of answers, but I just CANT understand why my code does not work.
Can you please help?

```
void reverse_LList_R_fail(Node** head) {

    Node* current = *head;
    if(current->next == nullptr) {
        *head = current;
        return;
    }

    reverse_LList_R_fail(&(current)->next);
    current->next->next = current;
    current->next = nullptr;

}
```

PS: in my LList implementation, I defined Node* head = nullptr; as a global variable, and in my assigment, I have to use a double pointer.

Comment: Post all relevant code, and what does not work?

Comment: "my code does not work" This is not a useful description of the problem that allows us to help you.

Comment: 1) Please provide [mre]. 2) Did you try stepping through your code, **line-by-line**, with a debugger, while investigating the values of every variable, at each execution step, taking note, of where the execution doesn't match your expectations?

Comment: Work with an example say A->B->C->null by hand. You can easily see why it does not work . And please post what you found .

Comment: @Borna Jelic I do not know who down-voted your question but it is evident that the task is not simple for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function does not check whether `*head` is equal to `nullptr`. So the function has undefined behavior.

Also the original head passed through pointer to the function is not changed.

The function can look the following way

```
 void reverse_LList_R_fail( Node **head ) 
 { 
     if ( *head && ( *head )->next ) 
     { 
         Node *current = *head; 
         *head = ( *head )->next; 
         reverse_LList_R_fail( head ); 
         current->next->next = current; 
         current->next = nullptr; 
     }         
 }
```

And the function is called like

```
reverse_LList_R_fail( &head );
```

Comment: Thank you Vlad, but here you said "Also the original head passed through pointer to the function is not changed.". Isnt it(head) changed in the exit condition for my recursion where *head = current is written?

Comment: @BornaJelic No, it Is not the original head that are changed.